# Wordpress Bootstrap Text Editor WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, editor, wysiwyg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hope I finally found some really plain WP theme with Bootstrap 3, but now I want to format my content in WP' WYSIWYG text editor. For example I need to create grid, table, buttons, etc.

Finding any plugin seems impossible. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very broad.

A easy solution will be to add some buttons to the default editor, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

> Adding Buttons There is a simple (if you understand the Plugin API and
>   hooks) means of adding your own buttons to TinyMCE in WordPress on the
>   TinyMCE Custom Buttons page. See also Plugin API Rich Text Editor
>   Filters for more information.

Or you could great shortcodes for your function and use b.e. http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/ (Allows you to create custom shortcodes, with a additional addon), see: http://gndev.info/kb/how-to-create-custom-shortcode/